# Highcharts: how to separate stacked columns on datetime axis

Tags: highcharts

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uovD8.png)

I have multiple series shown on a datetime axis.

The problem is that the same series can have multiple entries for the same date.

Is there a way to separate these stacks based on another ID variable that I'm passing to highcharts?

This example is close to what I need: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/

```
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
    stack: 'female'
}, {
    name: 'Janet',
    data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
    stack: 'female'
}]
```

But instead of defining stack by series, I need it defined by individual data points.

Answer (score 0):

> But instead of defining stack by series, I need it defined by
>   individual data points.

Unfortunately, it will require a lot of custom code. However, there is a better solution with the use of [linkedTo](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.linkedTo) and [id](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.id) series properties. When you have the same series which have multiple entries for the same date split them as a separate series with different `stack`. Set for example `id = '1'` in the first series and `linkedTo = '1'` in the second one. When two series are linked, only the first one appears in the legend.

Example code:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'male',
    id: 'john'
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
    stack: 'female',
    linkedTo: 'john'
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    stack: 'male'
  }, {
    name: 'Janet',
    data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
    stack: 'female'
  }]
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ure08d4k/6/